# Multiple Projects with Common Assemblies in .NET

Tags: .net

I have a solution with multiple projects. Each project is using an assembly that is coppied to their corresponding output directories after build. Most of these projects have a common dll. For example ProjectA.dll is used by ProjectB, ProjectC, and ProjectD. Is it possible to simply put ProjectA.dll into one central folder and let the other class library projects point to it? I know about GAC but they say that you should only use it if multiple applications use a particular assembly.

EDIT:
When deployed, I want the following structure:

```
Bin
-> ProjectA.dll
-> Other Projects
----> ProjectB.dll
----> ProjectC.dll
MyProject.exe
```

Will projectA.dll still be referenced properly by ProjectB.dll and ProjectC.dll?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all your projects are in the same solution, Visual Studio knows how to manage this dependency. Simply add a project reference to ProjectA in ProjectB, ProjectC, ProjectD. To do this, right click references in solution explorer, go to add reference, click projects tab.

This will create a build dependency causing ProjectA to build any time ProjectB, C or D is built and those projects will reference the DLL out of the correct ProjectA\bin\Debug or \bin\Release (or whatever solution config you are currently in) ensuring everything is all nice and up to date and the DLL doesn't need to be copied all over the place.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does this still work even if your application is deployed? I am planning this kind of structure when my program is deployed. (See edited question)

Comment: you should take a look at this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12215/Assemblies-locating-binding-and-deploying

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider creating a nuget package for project A. If you don't have a server that can publish you can copy it to a network share, then set visual studio up to monitor that location. Hth.

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a note of that.